# Default Width of UITableViewCell in iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uitableview

In iphone 6, I am making a custom UITableViewCell. In init function when I do,

```
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

And then , I check the frame it comes out to be `320 X 44` instead of `375 X 44`. However, in `layoutSubviews`, it comes fine. I am checking this on iphone 6 simulator. Is there a way I can get the correct size in init only ?

Answer (score 1):

You will find the width with the tableview size and it's 44px on height by default, so you can override initWithStyle method and add tableview width parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can't.
Same issue has been following the iPad for the last few years, and I don't believe anything has changed now. 
New cell always has 320 px width at first. 
You can implement some custom logic, such as laying out subviews not depending on current bounds, but on desired future bounds.

But anyway, if you're adapting the interface to iPhone 6 & 6 Plus, you obviously also support iPhone 5, which has width 320px. Then just create "resizable" cell that looks good with any cell width.

Comment: Thanks, I finally made another layer of custom cell and overwrite the init.